# Windows languages without framework dependency?

Tags: windows

I want to develop application which will communicate with my php server. This application will be used by multiple users. Please suggest any language which does not depend upon like c# depends upon dot net framework. I want something simple like gtalk which does not need to install any dependent framework.

Comment: "Something simple like gtalk" -- GTalk as in the Google chat service? Do you have any idea how complex GTalk is behind the scenes?

Comment: I mean I want to develop my application which should not depend upon any framework. Just like gtalk or any other public application which does not require any framework at the time of installation

Comment: Well then... C? If you want any useful answer you'll need to provide more information. First of all, we're talking about a standalone Windows application here? Secondly, what languages are you comfortable with? Third, does this question actually have anything to do with PHP or gtalk or could you tag it better?

Comment: Do you think I can good interface?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to create your client for GTalk then it is possible by using [this library](http://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/) .but you have to create a intelligent application for this.If you feel any ambiguity , feel free to ask

Comment: Which language will I suppose to use?

Comment: You can use php for this .. As well as GTalk also giving support for JAVA and c# but you are not going for c# so its ok

Comment: Do you think I can build framework independent language using this library. Please note I want to develop desktop application

Comment: Please tell me if I can use win32 or vb 6 ?

Comment: Listen .. Desktop application mean You want to build a application which will run on any OS. So you should need support of .net framework for c# application and JVM for java.I suggest you JAVA because it is Platform independent language and you will face almost no or minor issue if you shift your application on any OS

Comment: Alright but gtalk at the time of installation does not require framework. Although it is the desktop application

Comment: The Windows API, informally WinAPI, is Microsoft's core set of application programming interfaces (APIs) available in the Microsoft Windows operating systems. The name Windows API collectively refers to a number of different platform implementations that are often referred to by their own names (for example, Win32 API ... you will face platform issues either you are on win32 or vb6

Comment: Please suggest as If I want to develop light weight application. Which language do u prefer now

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18046/discussion-between-ssk-and-fawad)